# Rails redirect without changing URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've some piece of ruby/rails code.

In one of the controllers say foo i have an action doo which does something and I want to redirect to another controller say bar and action say dar.

When I use redirect_to then URL in the address bar changes to /bar/dar while if I use render then I don't know how to render another controller's view.

I am using rails 2.3.5 so render_component is unavailable for use (which i found could be really really useful for me) -- so as a shortcut if you have any idea of alternate for render_component that will help me infinitely.

Any ideas?

[If am unclear please ask me details]

Comment: Do you really want to redirect, or do you just want to chain the action?

Comment: i want to redirect (this means i want to execute the action in another controller and then show the corresponding view) 

another requirement is that i don't want URL in browser to change

Comment: Do you need to send any params in another controller(ex. :id, :page)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a real redirect, could you use an AJAX call to hit the action and pull in the appropriate views?

Answer (score 0):

You can render the same partial from both views. You'll have a view for each action and in each of the views you'll have something like <%= render :partial => "partials/form" %>.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the action (like calling a function) and then render the template. But accordingly to the MVC pattern you should manage your controller-side logic on the controller and then loads the propper view.